# Plotting co-ords from an embedded system on Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have an embedded system that connects to a gps receiver and retrieves longitude and latitude values ,now I want to plot these values on Google Maps using its API, can I get an heads up how to go about that?
tried surfing google but didn't get anything straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(YOUR_LATITUDE,YOUR_LONGITUDE))
        .title("Hello world"));
```

here mMap is GoogleMap object.

[more inforamation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#add_a_marker)

[develoer docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2)